# Change php code in vs code in different files

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I want to change the version (or any other var) of my php project across all php files.

How can i do it for all automatically (like rename symbol/F2 etc)?

```
<?php 
/**
 * nameitso
 * 
 * @package datpackage
 * @version v0.5
```

Comment: have you considered something like composer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use notepad++ and regex.
do replace `$.*version v([0-9\.]).*^` by `3.5`